# Integration using trigonometric subtitutions

Tags: integration

> Calculate the following integral:
>   $$ \int \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}}\,dx$$

I tried solving using trigonometric substitutions of secΦ. Then I tried again using  hyperbolic substitution.

Comment: Can you show your working using those substitutions?

Answer (score 1):

Since $2x^2+x-3=2\left(\left(x+\frac14\right)^2-\frac{25}{16}\right)$, you should substitute $x=\frac54\sec t-\frac14$ so $$\sec t=\frac{4x+1}{5},\,\tan t=\frac25\sqrt{4x^2+2x-6}.$$The integral becomes $$\int\frac{\frac54\sec^2t+\frac34\sec tdt}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{5}{4\sqrt{2}}\tan t+\frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}}\ln|\sec t+\tan t|+C\\=\frac12\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}+\frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}}\ln\left|4x+1+2\sqrt{4x^2+2x-6}\right|+C^\prime,$$with $C^\prime:=C-\ln 5$.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to proceed without any substitution,

$$\int \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}}dx=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{4x+4}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}}dx=\frac{1}{4}(\int \frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}}dx+\int \frac{3}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}}dx)=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{d(2x^2+x-3)}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}}+\int \frac{3/4}{\sqrt2{[(x+1/4)^2-25/16]}}dx$$

Can you make it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}} dx = \frac{1}{4} \int\left(\frac {4x+1 +3}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}} \right)dx =\frac{1}{4} \left(\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}} + \frac {3 dx}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}+ \frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+1/4)^2-\frac{7}{4}}}$$ $$ \implies I=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2x^2+x-3}+\frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}}\log\left[x+1/4+\sqrt{x^2+x/2-3/2}\right]+C$$